# Web3.py contract owner address return null address

Tags: smartcontracts, web3py

I am trying to get the owner's address of a contract, but the address is always coming back with a 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 address. Can someone validate if I am missing something in my code to be able to parse the address?

The API key was masked from the code below.

```
from web3 import Web3

providerURL = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/[api-key]'
abi ='[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"name","type":"string"},{"internalType":"string","name":"symbol","type":"string"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxNftSupply","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"saleStart","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"approved","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"ApprovalForAll","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"BAYC_PROVENANCE","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MAX_APES","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"REVEAL_TIMESTAMP","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"apePrice","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"baseURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"emergencySetStartingIndexBlock","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"flipSaleState","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getApproved","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"isApprovedForAll","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"maxApePurchase","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"numberOfTokens","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mintApe","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"reserveApes","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"saleIsActive","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"setApprovalForAll","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"baseURI","type":"string"}],"name":"setBaseURI","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"provenanceHash","type":"string"}],"name":"setProvenanceHash","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"revealTimeStamp","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setRevealTimestamp","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"setStartingIndex","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"startingIndex","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"startingIndexBlock","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"index","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenByIndex","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"index","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenOfOwnerByIndex","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]'
contractAddress = '0xBC4CA0EdA7647A8aB7C2061c2E118A18a936f13D'

#connect to remote provider
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(providerURL))
print('Connected to provider:', w3.isConnected())

#create an instance of the contract
contractInstance = w3.eth.contract(address=contractAddress, abi=abi)

#Task-01
owner = contractInstance.functions.owner().call()
print('owner: ',owner)
```

Comment: I'm getting a 404 when trying to ping `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/` .  Are you sure you have the right endpoint?

Comment: I removed my api key from the provider URL

Comment: Right but even if I ping `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/1234567`,  I should at least get a "BAD API KEY" response don't you think? Instead I still get a 404

Comment: @Jamie_D This is because it is suposed to be a `POST` request.

Comment: Your right  .... getting `invalid project id` now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owner of this contract is indeed the null address. The returned value is correct. Why did you assume otherwise?

Comment: I was probably looking at the wrong thing on etherscan and got down a rabbit hole. Thanks for confirming.